# PHP Ajax realtime file transfer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

in server side i'm trying to transfer file from other site with Ajax and realtime ability, for create this ability after get url from user i'm wrote simple ajax request :

but my ajax could not alert me as an realtime response such as `10% transfer` in each file transfer.

```
var url="fileTransfer.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlFileTransfer,
    data: {url: url},
    success: function (fileTransfer) {
        /* ALERT AFTER FILE TRANSFER */
    }
});
```

**fileTransfer.php**

```
$path = 'newfile.zip';
$url = $_POST['url'];
$newfname = $path;
echo 'Starting Download!<br>';
$file = fopen($url, "rb");
if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen($newfname, "wb");
    if ($newf)
        while (!feof($file)) {
            fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8), 1024 * 8);
            echo '1 MB File Chunk Written!<br>';
        }
}
if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
}
if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
}
echo 'Finished!';
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @Epodax my ajax response is not realtime when application is transfering file

Comment: Is it a progress bar you want? If so where is your attempt of creating one. If not, can you explain in more detail what you wish to achieve... If you're trying to use PHP to return some form of progress then it won't work as the ajax call will wait for the PHP to finish executing before giving a response meaning your `while` loop will be complete before replying to the ajax call.